# declaring a priority_queue in c++ with a custom comparator

Tags: c++, std, priority-queue

I'm trying to declare a `priority_queue of nodes`, using `bool Compare(Node a, Node b)` as the comparator function (which is outside the node class).

What I currently have is:

```
priority_queue<Node, vector<Node>, Compare> openSet;
```

For some reason, I'm getting `Error: "Compare" is not a type name`

Changing the declaration to `priority_queue <Node, vector<Node>, bool Compare>`

gives me `Error: expected a '>'`

I've also tried:

```
priority_queue<Node, vector<Node>, Compare()> openSet;
priority_queue<Node, vector<Node>, bool Compare()> openSet;
priority_queue<Node, vector<Node>, Compare<Node, Node>> openSet;
```

How should I correctly declare my `priority_queue`?

Answer (score 215, accepted):

*Note - You may also want to check other answers, especially the one with decltype and lambda*

---

You should declare a class `Compare` and overload `operator()` for it like this:

```
class Foo
{

};

class Compare
{
public:
    bool operator() (Foo, Foo)
    {
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<Foo, std::vector<Foo>, Compare> pq;
    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you for some reasons can't make it as class, you could use `std::function` for it:

```
class Foo
{

};

bool Compare(Foo, Foo)
{
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<Foo, std::vector<Foo>, std::function<bool(Foo, Foo)>> pq(Compare);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. I never thought to make a separate class.

Would the first example be considered better style?

Comment: @StevenMorad, I prefer to use class with overloaded `operator()`, it looks simpler.

Comment: @soon Why do we overload the operator () ? Is this linked to how priority_queues are implemented internally? overloading > or < makes sense intuitively, but () operator not so much

Comment: @Piyush, the question is about passing a custom comparator to the `pritority_queue`. It is possible to overload `operator<` and use built-in `std::less` comparator, however, the `bool Compare(Node a, Node b)` declared outside of the class `Node`, according to the question.

Comment: @Piyush the syntax of using () is about passing a function as a parameter to another function, not about the specific operators. This is also known as a functor. See this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object

Comment: @awesoon would a struct work, or is it necessary to use class only?

Comment: @AbhayPatil struct will work just fine. They're the same as classes in C++, the only difference is default access level - struct members are public by default.

Comment: NOTE: You should pass `Compare`  to the constructor of priority_queue in the second example.

Comment: @awesoon in the first example, why is it required to declare another class `Compare`. can we overload the operator in the `Foo` class?

Comment: @awesoon i get an error doing so. can you please help?
https://ideone.com/VVHb1L

Answer (score 124):

The accepted answer shows how to use a class or a `std::function` as comparator. We can also pass a function pointer, as [cute_ptr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40573224/7328782) already showed. However, the syntax to do so is much simpler than shown there:

```cpp
class Node;
bool Compare(Node a, Node b);

std::priority_queue<Node, std::vector<Node>, decltype(&Compare)> openSet(Compare);
```

That is, there is no need to explicitly encode the function's type, you can let the compiler do that for you using `decltype`.

This is very useful if the comparator is a lambda. You cannot specify the type of a lambda in any other way than using `decltype`. For example:

```cpp
auto compare = [](Node a, Node b) { return a.foo < b.foo; }
std::priority_queue<Node, std::vector<Node>, decltype(compare)> openSet(compare);
```

Comment: This is fantastic, I wonder if there are any potential traps (issues) here.  Would love to see this answer get more visibility and discussion.

Comment: @Apollys: I use this method regularly (usually `Compare` is a lambda, which is impossible to write a declaration for), I don't know of any traps.

Comment: If you were to do this for a lambda function, where would you put the body of the lambda function? Would you store it in a variable `f` beforehand and then replace `Compare` with `f`?

Comment: @EricAuld: Yes, `Compare` can be a lambda function there, as in `auto Compare = [](){};`. But you need to use `decltype(Compare)`, rather than `decltype(&Compare)`.

Comment: The pretty and concise notation without a function object (`decltype(&Compare)`) compiled but produced a segmentation fault with Debian clang version 11.0.1-2
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu. When I replaced it with a function object, it works. Compiler bug?!

Comment: @BitTickler: I would think that is highly unlikely to be a compiler bug. Changing one part of a program can bring to light bugs in other parts. I would start by building with the AdressSanitizer on, see if you can catch any out of bounds writes and so on. If that fails, try to create a [mre]. If you manage that, and the example is so simple that there is no way the error could be yours, then open a ticket at the clang project.

Comment: @CrisLuengo There is not a single pointer in my whole, quite short program. And from the Compare class I call the same compare function I wanted to use initially. If it is not a compiler bug, it could still be an implementation bug of the priority queue... But I will try to knock up some canonical example, which removes any doubt.

Comment: @CrisLuengo [https://gist.github.com/ruffianeo/55ebe9f921d4f057d979763afc248b23] - the canonical example.

Comment: @BitTickler: You need to include a pointer to the comparator function when you construct the queue: `Seqs pq(char_range_compare);`. The template arguments specify the function type (i.e. what parameters it takes and what type it returns), it doesn't specify an actual function to call. I don't know why this doesn't give a compile-time error. GCC also happily compiles your code without a warning, and produces the same seg fault. It's because there's an attempt to call a function at address 0x0000.

Answer (score 31):

The third template parameter must be a class who has `operator()(Node,Node)` overloaded.
So you will have to create a class this way:

```cpp
class ComparisonClass {
public:
    bool operator() (Node obj1, Node obj2) {
        //comparison code here
    }
};
```

And then you will use this class as the third template parameter like this:

```cpp
priority_queue<Node, vector<Node>, ComparisonClass> q;
```

Comment: The operator method must be public.

Comment: The third template does not need to be a class. It can be the type of a function.

Comment: According to [cpluplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/priority_queue/): _This may be a **function pointer** or function object_

Comment: @Mic can we define the operator() in the Node class itself?

Answer (score 17):

Answering your question directly:

> I'm trying to declare a `priority_queue` of nodes, using `bool Compare(Node a, Node b) as the comparator function`
>
> What I currently have is:
>
> ```
> priority_queue<Node, vector<Node>, Compare> openSet;
> ```
>
> For some reason, I'm getting Error:
>
> ```
> "Compare" is not a type name
> ```

The compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong: `Compare` is not a type name, but an instance of a function that takes two `Nodes` and returns a `bool`.
What you need is to specify the function pointer type:
`std::priority_queue<Node, std::vector<Node>, bool (*)(Node, Node)> openSet(Compare)`

Answer (score 15):

You have to define the compare first. There are 3 ways to do that:

1. use class
2. use struct (which is same as class)
3. use lambda function.

It's easy to use class/struct because easy to declare just write this line of code above your executing code

```
struct compare{
  public:
  bool operator()(Node& a,Node& b) // overloading both operators 
  {
      return a.w < b.w: // if you want increasing order;(i.e increasing for minPQ)
      return a.w > b.w // if you want reverse of default order;(i.e decreasing for minPQ)
   }
};
```

Calling code:

```
priority_queue<Node,vector<Node>,compare> pq;
```

Answer (score 11):

One can also use a lambda function.

```
auto Compare = [](Node &a, Node &b) { //compare };
std::priority_queue<Node, std::vector<Node>, decltype(Compare)> openset(Compare);
```

Answer (score 5):

In case this helps anyone :

```
static bool myFunction(Node& p1, Node& p2) {}
priority_queue <Node, vector<Node>, function<bool(Node&, Node&)>> pq1(myFunction);
```

Answer (score 3):

In the priority queue, there is a predefined boolean function "operator<()", try to overload this function as per your requirement.

```
bool operator<(const Node& x,const Node& y){
    return x.data>y.data;
}

priority_queue<Node> min_heap;
```

Comment: I watched this, but I didn't understand why he said operator< is wrong.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbiF1HDcG7U&list=PLs3KjaCtOwSZ2tbuV1hx8Xz-rFZTan2J1&index=97

Comment: @Kargath The video says that for some use cases, the sorting does not relate to a “less than” comparison. Defining `<` to impose your custom sorting would be confusing in this case, because it wouldn’t really be a “less than” comparison. `<` would return true if one object comes before the other in the sorting, rather than if one is smaller than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++ 20, we can more concisely use a lambda for the comparator inline, without needing to assign it to a separate variable. This is because lambdas without any captures are now default constructible.

For example:

```cpp
std::priority_queue<Node, std::vector<Node>, 
                       decltype([](Node& a, Node& b){return a.x < b.x;})> pq;
```

Note that we did not need to pass the lambda itself to the constructor, but only its type to the third template parameter. No repetition is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

With latest c++ standard, you can actually declare a lambda function for comparator which would make the code much cleaner. Here is a sample code:

```
#include <queue>

class Foo
{
    public:
        int i;
};


int main()
{
    auto comparator = [](const Foo& a, const Foo& b) {
        return a.i > b.i;
    };

    std::priority_queue<Foo, std::vector<Foo>, decltype(comparator)>  pq(comparator);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This was possible since C++11, definitely not the latest standard. Also, when you wrote this, there were already two answers showing how to use a lambda function in this way. Please make sure you add value when you write an answer.

Answer (score -1):

With the help of `struct` also we can do this. The code will go something like below.

```
struct myCompare{
    bool operator()(Node &a, Node &b){
        // Your own custom logic to compare the two nodes and return a boolean value.
    }
}

priority_queue<Node, vector<Node>, myCompare> openSet;
```

Answer (score -2):

prefer struct, and it's what std::greater do

```
struct Compare {
  bool operator()(Node const&, Node &) {}
}
```