# Why function comparator doesn't work in priority queue like it does in sort?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, compare, priority-queue

We have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16111337/3370168), which discusses how to use a comparator in `priority_queue` in C++. He gives the overloaded `operator` `class` (or `struct`) as the third argument and it works fine. But `bool` function doesn't work. Why ? But it works fine in `sort` of the `<algorithm>`. When I looked into docs ([priority_queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/) && [algo/sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)), both of them take the `class Compare` as their optional third argument.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool cmp (const int &a,const int &b){ return a > b; }

struct cmp2
{
    bool operator() (const int &p1,const int &p2)
    {
        return p1 > p2;
    }
};

int main ()
{
//  freopen("test.txt","r",stdin);
    int a[10];
    vector<int> b(10);
    sort( a , a + 10, cmp );    // working cool
    sort( b.begin() , b.end() , cmp);   // working great
    priority_queue<int, vector<int> , cmp2 > x;    // as usual, working....
    priority_queue<int, vector<int> , cmp > y;   // not working why ?

    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
A:\pqvsarray.cpp    In function 'int main()':
27  40  A:\pqvsarray.cpp    [Error] type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Tp, class _Sequence, class _Compare> class std::priority_queue'
27  40  A:\pqvsarray.cpp    [Error] expected a type, got 'cmp'
27  43  A:\pqvsarray.cpp    [Error] invalid type in declaration before ';' token
```

**So, why the difference ?**

Comment: Because priority_queue template requires a type, but you are giving it a function pointer.

Comment: So, how / why does `sort` take a `function pointer` ?

Comment: @SelçukCihan According to [the priority_queue documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/), it can be a function pointer: *This can be a function pointer or a function object*

Comment: @azam because in sort, you are actually calling a method. However with the priority_queue, what you are doing is specifying what kind of a priority queue you want by giving the template parameters. That is the difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a function with `std::priority_queue` as well. The difference in what you're doing is that you pass the function to `std::sort` as a function parameter, but you try to define the function as a template parameter of the queue. This obviously does not work because the third argument is a type argument as the error explains. Besides, you cannot even have pointer or reference template arguments.

If you take a look at the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue), you'll find that the queue has a constructor for passing the comparison object. *That's* where you must pass the function.

There is a difference with `std::sort`.  Sort is a function, and you can let the compiler [deduce](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) it's template arguments so you don't have to specify them explicitly. The queue is a class template, and template arguments of a class template can not be deduced (not in this context at least).

The template argument is defaulted to `std::less<typename Container::value_type>`, but you don't want to use that. Therefore, you must specify explicitly the type of the comparison object. You specify it where you're now trying to pass the object. How to get the type of the function pointer/reference, you may ask. You can do it like this: `decltype(&cmp)`. If you have an outdated compiler that does not support `decltype` yet, then you'll need to specify the type without it: `bool (&)(const int&, const int&)`.

Here is an example of how you would create a queue that uses your function.

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(&cmp)> x(cmp);
```

Comment: Yes, `bool (&)(const int&, const int&)` as the third argument is working. `decltype` is in C++11 if I'm not wrong. And +1 for explaining well.

Comment: Yup, `decltype` was added in C++11 indeed.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message implies, functions cannot be used as template parameters. The `priority_queue` will copy an object of the *comparison type*. For example, this might be `std::less<int>`, where an object of that type is `std::less<int>()`, and it being called is `std::less<int>()(x, y)`. In C++11, you could use `decltype`, but in C++03 the "canonical" way is to create a "functor" (an entire type dedicated to being used as a function object.) This is one of the reasons why [lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7627098/3370168) were created.

Comment: Nice, for spotting the deficiency of C++ and explaining the reason for the advent of `lambda`s in C++11.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in compiler errors.
The third template parameter of priority queue is a comparator type (like structure or classes) and not a function.

Comment: According to [the priorty_queue documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/), it should be possible to use a function.

Comment: @Aracthor: It is possible. You just have to pass the right argument to the right place. You pass the function pointer's type as a template argument for `priority_queue`, and you pass your actual function pointer as an argument to the constructor. This is the exact same situation as you have with `std::sort`, except there, the type is inferred, which you can do with a call to a function template (like `std::sort`), but not with an instantiation of a class template object (like `std::priority_queue`).

Comment: It would be better if you'd have explained a bit about the "*Why?*". But, thanks!