# Create a Min Priority Queue contain different types of event in C++

Tags: c++

```
class Event
{
    // Overloading the comparison operators
    friend bool operator < (const Event& e1, const Event& e2);
    friend bool operator == (const Event& e1, const Event& e2);

public:
    Event() {};
    enum EvtType {arrival_1, arrival_2, arrival_3, arrival_4, arrival_5, arrival_6};
    Event(EvtType type, double etime):
        _type(type), _etime(etime) {}

    EvtType get_Type()
    {
       return _type;
    }

    double get_time()
    {
       return _etime;
    }

protected:
    EvtType _type;
    double _etime;
};



bool operator < (const Event& e1, const Event& e2)
{
return e2._etime < e1._etime;
}

bool operator == (const Event& e1, const Event& e2)
{
     if(e1._etime != e2._etime)return false;
     if(e1._type == (Event::arrival_2 && Event::arrival_3 &&    Event::arrival_4 && Event::arrival_5 && Event::arrival_6)) return true;
     return false;
}


priority_queue <Event> FEL;
```

I have create a class called "Event" which contain several types of event and time to occur. After this, I would like to create a priority queue "FEL" to contain these events and their times. However, in general priority queue always sort the event base all max value.

How can I sort these event based on min value, so that when i call the FEL.top(), I will get the event with smallest time.

I have tried to solve this by using bool operator. But It still has a problem. Anyone please helps to fix this would be grateful.

Thank You very much

Comment: [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) allows you to pass along any comparator function. It can be the default [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), or another lstandard comparator like [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater), or even a custom function or callable object.

Comment: Is there  anyway to use bool operator to set it, so every time when i call FEL.top(), i will obtain the event with smallest time automatically ? Please demonstrate me some codes.

Comment: Yes, by implementing an `operator<` function for your `Event` class. That's all you have to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111337/declaring-a-priority-queue-in-c-with-a-custom-comparator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `std::priority_queue` container adapter is a max-queue construct. It utilizes a "less" comparator to sort the queued items in a way where the  *maximum* item is always first. Thus, if you want to have the *smallest* items first, you need a comparator that does the opposite of what may first seem natural to you.

A quick example, suppose you had a vector of `int` values and you wanted them prioritized *largest* to *smallest*. This is the natural, default operational action of `std::priority_queue<int>`. it uses `std::less<int>` to determine the order of the items (which come before, which come after), and given those outcomes, ensures the *largest* appears first in the queue. Consider the following example, which makes two `int` queues, one which uses `std::less<int>` the other `std::greater<int>` for comparison:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 rng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1,10);

    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::less<int>> q1;
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int>> q2;

    for (int i=0; i<20; ++i)
    {
        int value = dist(rng);
        q1.push(value);
        q2.push(value);
    }

    std::cout << "q1: ";
    for (; !q1.empty(); q1.pop())
        std::cout << q1.top() << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "q2: ";
    for (; !q2.empty(); q2.pop())
        std::cout << q2.top() << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Output** (varies)

```
q1: 10 10 8 8 8 7 6 6 5 5 5 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 1 1 
q2: 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 7 8 8 8 10 10
```

As you can see, a queue that uses a "greater" comparator for its less-op when determining ordering delivers what you seek. We just need to fit such a thing into your queue and its `Event` type

---

You need a comparator that does the opposite of the default ordering:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>

class Event
{
public:
    enum EvtType { arrival_1, arrival_2, arrival_3, arrival_4, arrival_5, arrival_6 };

    Event(EvtType type = arrival_1, double etime = 0.0)
        : _type(type)
        , _etime(etime)
    {}

    EvtType get_Type() const { return _type; };
    double get_Time() const { return _etime; }

protected:
    EvtType _type;
    double _etime;
};

struct EventLess
{
    bool operator()(const Event& lhs, const Event& rhs) const
    {
        return (lhs.get_Time() > rhs.get_Time());
    }
};

int main()
{

    std::priority_queue<Event, std::vector<Event>, EventLess> q;
    q.push(Event(Event::arrival_1, 3.0));
    q.push(Event(Event::arrival_2, 2.0));
    q.push(Event(Event::arrival_3, 1.0));
    q.push(Event(Event::arrival_1, 1.0));
    q.push(Event(Event::arrival_2, 2.0));
    q.push(Event(Event::arrival_3, 3.0));

    while (!q.empty())
    {
        const Event& e = q.top();
        std::cout << e.get_Type() << ' ' << e.get_Time() << '\n';
        q.pop();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
2 1
0 1
1 2
1 2
0 3
2 3
```

Note the time value (the second) is ordered smallest to largest. This is because our comparator `EventLess` says "items with larger times are 'less' than items with smaller times", and the queue naturally pushes those down the queue rather than promoting them to the top. What makes this work is simply this:

```
struct EventLess
{
    bool operator()(const Event& lhs, const Event& rhs) const
    {
        return (lhs.get_Time() > rhs.get_Time());
    }
};
```

Here we're telling the caller (the queue adapter) that given two elements, the one with a *greater* time value should be considered "less" than something with a smaller time value. The queue then orders the items largest to smallest.

I think you understand the need for custom comparison. I just don't think you understood how the `std::priority_queue` works. It's a max-queue. You just have to convince it your definition of `max` is something different.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful. Now I understand more about priority Queue.

Comment: @Rocky If this answered your question, then please mark it as the accepted answer using the tick symbol. If it did not, then please clarify what else people can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a `std::priority_queue<Event>` in the first place, based solely on the shown code. `Event` does not implement the `<` operator, which `std::priority_queue<Event>` requires.

You either have the `<` operator defined, but it was not included in the shown code, or you must be already passing an optional comparator class to your existing `std::priority_queue`, that specifies strict weak ordering for all the `Event`s.

In either case, simply change the appropriate comparison function to compare your `Event`s in the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a custom comparator type parameter to `std::priority_queue`.
But before we do that let's define the operator `>` for your `Event` class:

```
bool Event::operator>(Event const& other) {
    return _etime > other._etime;
}
```

You can also define it in the same fashion you did for the other operators. Now, your queue's type becomes:

```
std::priority_queue<Event, std::vector<Event>, std::greater<Event>> FEL;
```

This will have the effect to put the `Event` object with the lowest timestamp `_etime` on top.