# Why is STL priority queue incorrectly sorrting my class objects

Tags: c++, stl, polymorphism, priority-queue

I have overloaded the `<` operator as shown but every time the program is run my class objects are sorted seemingly randomly.

```cpp
class Node
{
int decimal_value
public:
    Node(int decimal) : decimal_value(decimal)
    {}
    friend bool operator<(const Node& p1, const Node& p2);
};

 bool operator<(const Node& p1, const Node& p2)
{
    return p1.decimal_value < p2.decimal_value;
}

int main()
{
    Node* n1= new Node(5);
    Node* n2 = new Node(4);

    priority_queue<Node*> my_q;
    my_q.push(n1);
    my_q.push(n2);
}
```

Is it possibly due to my use of pointers to Nodes rather than Nodes themselves? And if so how can I fix this?

Comment: When creating a [mcve] to show us, please make sure it replicates the problem you have, and don't contain any other unrelated errors.

Comment: Your operator overload has *nothing* to do with a priority queue of pointers. They're being compared at face-value using stock pointer value comparison. Make a custom comparator type as the additional argument to the queue.

Comment: And yes, the problem is most likely because you have a queue of *pointers*, so the comparison operator that will be invoked is `bool operator<(Node*, Node*)`.

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111337/declaring-a-priority-queue-in-c-with-a-custom-comparator)

Comment: What would be wrong with `priority_queue<Node>`? And if you really must store pointers, you should store smart pointers (unless someone else is responsible for deallocating them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`priority_queue<Node*> my_q;` will compare elements of type `Node*` to sort, it will *not* dereference those pointers for you and call your overloaded operator. And comparison of unrelated pointers has <del>un</del>defined behaviour, but will yield no useful result in your case.

When you fixed this one, there will be another bug: You never initialize `decimal_value`, so it's value is undefined/random.

One solution would be to explicitly specify an comparator:

```
struct MyComparator {
    bool operator()(const Node*l, const Node*r) const {
        return l->decimal_value < r->decimal_value;
    }
};

std::priority_queue<Node*, std::vector<Node*>, MyComparator> q;
```

Comment: Comparison of unrelated pointers has [defined behavior](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.rel#4) (although it is only a partial ordering). Subtraction [does not](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#5).

Comment: I see, so is there no way to use a priority_queue to sort what the pointers are pointing to?

Comment: @Risen, I added a small example :)

Comment: @MaxLanghof Hm, I remember pointer comparison between unrelated pointers as UB as well. Could that possibly have changed with C++11? Unfortunately, not having access to older standards at the moment...

Comment: @Aconcagua In C++11 it was well-defined (although mostly unspecified): https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.rel#2. Similar for [n1905 from 2005](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf). Let me see if there's an older draft somewhere...

Comment: @MaxLanghof Well, C++11 I figured out myself – just that I'm old enough to have learned C++ with 98 standard...

Comment: @Aconcagua I was able to dig up a C++03 standard, and it's only unspecified there too: https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall11/CSCI-GA.2110-003/documents/c++2003std.pdf

Comment: @Aconcagua And here's C++98, also unspecified: http://www.lirmm.fr/~ducour/Doc-objets/ISO+IEC+14882-1998.pdf

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thanks! Seems as if I mixed up something myself long ago and retained it until today...