# std::greater on a an std::pair of a double and a class

Tags: c++, std, priority-queue, std-pair, min-heap

Does `std::greater` work when you have a `std::pair` of `int` and a class?

I am trying to create a priority queue of pairs, ordered by the first element:

```
std::priority_queue<std::pair<double, classA>, std::vector<std::pair<double, classA>>, std::greater<std::pair<double, classA>>> priorityQueue
```

But I get an error that says

> no match for 'operator<'`

And it alludes to the second element of the `std::pair`, which is of class type.

Is `std::greater` applied to the first and second elements of the `std::pair`?

Comment: [Here is the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::greater` is just a wrapper for a call to `operator <` of the template type.  For `std::pair` we can check the reference site [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) and we see it says

> Compares lhs and rhs lexicographically by `operator<`, that is, compares the first elements and only if they are equivalent, compares the second elements.

So, it uses the `operator <` of both types, which means your class type needs to supply it.  Since it doesn't you get the compiler error.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Since I don't have anything to compare in my class, how do I define operator< ?

Comment: @sometimesLazy I wouldn't.  What I would do is write a custom comparator that only looks at the `double` part of the pair.  For how, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111337/declaring-a-priority-queue-in-c-with-a-custom-comparator

Comment: Thank you for this! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `classA` type needs to define an `operator<`.
Notice that `std::pair` compares lexicographically.