# C++ how to declare an array of priority_queue with customed comparator

Tags: c++, lambda, std, priority-queue

With the idea from:
[declaring a priority_queue in c++ with a custom comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111337/declaring-a-priority-queue-in-c-with-a-custom-comparator) ,

I tried to use lambda as comparator for the priority_queue, but when I tried to declare an array of it, error comes.

code:

```
class Klass{public:int raw_hash;int name;};

bool PriorByRaw(Klass a, Klass b){return a.raw_hash > b.raw_hash;}

auto prior = [](Klass a, Klass b){return PriorByRaw(a, b);};

//here comes the error before "[10]": expected a ';'

priority_queue<Klass, vector<Klass>, decltype(prior)> pq(prior)[10];
```

The question is how can I declared an array of priority_queue in this manner? Or is there any other solution?
As one day I may need a priority que which use other functions as comparator (say "PriorByName"), overriding the less function for the "Klass" looks not good.

I've tried but didn't work:

```
priority_queue<Klass, vector<Klass>, decltype(prior)> pq(prior)[10];

priority_queue<Klass, vector<Klass>, decltype(prior)> (pq(prior))[10];
```

Comment: Just for clarity, you want an array of ten priority *queues* (note plurality) ? A custom comparator functor type would make that pretty easy. Alternatively, you could just do a stock vector fill with a fill pattern value of your custom construction.

Comment: Yes, I want ten priority queues (pq[0]~pq[9] for above sample code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following to achieve what you want:

```
bool PriorByRaw(Klass const & a, Klass const & b) { return a.raw_hash > b.raw_hash; }

class KlassCompare
{
public:
    bool operator() (Klass const & a, Klass const & b) const
    {
        return PriorByRaw(a, b);
    }
};
priority_queue<Klass, vector<Klass>, KlassCompare> pq[10];
```

Several comments:

1. I replaced passing the `Klass` objects by `const&` instead of by value, since this is more efficient. Is there any reason you passed it by value ?
2. The main issue is to replace the lambda with a comparator class with `operator()`. Using the lambda and `decltype(prior)` requires the compiler to construct a new instance of a lambda which is not allowed.
   MSVC gives the following error for using the lambda:

   *"error C3497: you cannot construct an instance of a lambda"*

   You can look `C3497` up if you'd like to get more info.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! The reason that I passed args by value is that I want it to be easy to understand, so I only coded the core part.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++ 20, lambdas without captures are default constructible, so you can just remove the attempted constructor call and make the array like so:

```cpp
priority_queue<Klass, vector<Klass>, decltype(prior)> pq[10];
```